# How to get rid of white edges

Tags: image-editing, paint.net

I've searched for the answer here and online, but to no avail.

MSPaint only allows 90 degree increment rotations, so I want to tessellate using Paint.net instead. But when I clone an image, it comes out with a white "shadow" around the whole edge (see attached image). In MSPaint, all I have to do is hit the "transparent" button to get rid of the "shadow," but in Paint.net, I don't know how.

I'm adding an example of my tessellations (most famous tessellator was [Escher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M._C._Escher#Tessellation); compilation of his tessies [here](http://mathstat.slu.edu/escher/index.php/Regular_Division_of_the_Plane_Drawings)):

[image]

[image: transparent]

Comment: What shadow? Do you mean the big white frame cutting the gray square?

Comment: Hi Wordster. Welcome to GDSE. Unfortunately I'm not sure I understand your question.  What do you mean by "when I clone an image"?  Any chance you could post an example of what you are actually trying to achieve? Software such as MSPaint and Paint.NET is very basic, and might not be suitable for what you are trying to do. In particular I'd say raster image editors are not the best for this. Much better to use a vector image editor.

Comment: @Rafael:  yes, the white frame cutting the lighter square.

Comment: @BillyKerr:  I've made scores of tessies with MSPaint, but the one drawback is, you can't rotate 1 degree increments, which limits which shapes you can use for your basic templates.  I don't get along with GIMP.  Even Paint.net is too Gimpy for me, but I need it for the rotation function.

Comment: Honestly, GIMP or even Photoshop wouldn't be my first choice either. This is really a job for a vector image editor - such as Illustrator (not free) or Inkscape (which is free).  Have a look into that.

Comment: I can do it just fine in MSPaint, but I need the rotation function, which Paint.net has.  I can't deal with complicated programs like Illustrator and Inkscape.  Surely there has got to be a simple way to remove the shadow?

Comment: @BillyKerr:  In addition to my comment directly above this one, there's also the problem that, like MSPaint, Inkscape doesn't allow you to rotate things except in 90 degree increments.

Comment: Inkscape 0.92 allows arbitrary rotations using the object rotation handles, stepped rotations of 15 degree increments while holding down CTRL while rotating with the handles, and specific angular rotations via the transformation rotation options.

Comment: Are you using layers in Paint.NET?

Comment: @Luciano:  trying, if at all possible, to avoid them.  I import my images from MSPaint into Paint.net (MSP doesn't use layers, ghastly things!).

Comment: I'm sorry it's not the answer you wanted, but it seems there's no other way around it except using layers :)

Answer (score 1):

Use layers. You'll have better control of the irregular edges of your objects. You can export a flat JPG after you finish manipulating the image to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

You will have more control over this kind of project using Inkscape, but the workflow to draw is different. I am just mentioning an idea.

On Paint.net you have two tools that will help you integrate your image. As Luciano mentioned Layers. That way you can manipulate each piece or row and column of elements.

I don't know if the white border is already a part of your image, in form of a halo.

[image]

One way to solve it is now using another blending mode, try "If darker" or multiply.

The first one will override any white zone with darker color when it overlaps, the second one will obscure any color combining it. But as the lines are so thin, it could not work.

A thicker black line will also help.

But, again, using vectors is a good option.